# タイムゾーンの設定変更が反映されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsでブログを作っています。

投稿日時を表示させているのですが、
世界時刻だったので日本時間に変更しようと

`config`の`application.rb`の設定を変更しました。
しかし変更されず調べてみると、どうやら`application.rb`は読み込まれていないことが分かりました。
何が原因でしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

以下を確認してみてください。

- `Time.now`の出力
- `Time.zone.now`の出力
- アプリケーションを再起動したか

console(`bundle exec rails console`)での確認

```
4.2.7.1@2.3.0 (main)> Time.zone
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007febd00fa528 @name="Tokyo", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Asia/Tokyo>>
```

設定が正しくない場合は、システム時刻（サーバの時刻）となります。
herokuというPaaSではシステム時刻がUTCなのですが、その場合以下のようになります。

```
4.2.7.1@2.3.1 (main)> Time.now
=> 2016-12-21 07:38:52 +0000
4.2.7.1@2.3.1 (main)> Time.zone.now
=> Wed, 21 Dec 2016 16:39:00 JST +09:00
4.2.7.1@2.3.1 (main)>
```

正しく設定されているファイルの内容を参考に記載します。

```
module MyService
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'    

    ・・・
end
```

時刻関係の記事としては以下が参考になります。

http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/cae89ee43c30f5d6fa2c

Comment: アプリケーションを再起動することで解決しました。

Comment: 解説していただき有り難うございます。